# Validate java compact profile for all dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I try to evaluate whether my java program as well as all of its dependencies (including transitive ones) fit the java compact3 profile.

I can compile my program with the `-profile compact3` compiler switch, but this will only check my program.

How can I automatically (e.g. using maven) validate that all dependencies meet the profile requirement?
I could checkout the source for all dependencies and build them manually with the above compiler switch, but this is impracticable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [jdeps-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marschall/jdeps-maven-plugin) that is suitable for your use case

Add this to `pom.xml`

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.marschall</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdeps-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <profile>true</profile>
        <recursive>true</recursive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then run

```
$ mvn jdeps:jdeps
```

Unfortunately the plugin does not support automatic failing of builds if profile requirements are not met, but one can write an external script to process the output.

e.g.

```
mvn jdeps:jdeps | awk '/    ->/ && /Full/ {print}'
```

Comment: There's an open issue for profile validation: https://github.com/marschall/jdeps-maven-plugin/issues/6